# Scale an absolutely positioned div from center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of divs positioned absolutely on a background image.

On the page will also be some buttons. When those are clicked different variables will trigger, shrinking and growing these divs.

Here is the javascript I'm currently using...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var title = 1;

$(".button1").click(function() {
title = 1;  
});

$(".button2").click(function() {
title = 2;  
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    console.log(title);
        if (title==1){
            $('.london').animate({ backgroundColor:'green', width:'50',  height:'50' }, 300);
        } else if (title==2){
            $('.london').animate({ backgroundColor:'red', width:'40',  height:'40' }, 300);
        }


});

});
```

As they are absolutely positioned they are scaled from the corner they are positioned with.

see an example [here](http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/universities/index.html).

What I need to do is shrink and grow these divs from their center point. The only solutions I've seen seem overly complicated.

I guess I could add a negative margin of half the divs width in the jQuery to counteract this? I'll try that if there are no better solutions

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be best if you could re-create this in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) as well as add some snippets of HTML and CSS to your question.

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle, i'm sure its simple enough but I'm slightly pressed for time. The link in the question contains a very basic example. I will add my jquery to the question though, thanks

Comment: Your negative margin idea seems fine to me. [In this basic example it works well](http://jsbin.com/sugiwirekeko/1/edit). Click the ball.

Comment: I don't know why someones added an apostrophe to 'divs', I appreciate constructive criticism, but why do people have the power to wrongly correct my grammar

Comment: The edit log says that you added the backticks to "divs"...

Comment: Thanks @misterManSam I guess I can save the width and height as a variable and always take half that variable and minus it from the margins (if that makes sense) Thanks

Comment: No problem. Now, I think this is a valid question, so you should post your implementation as an answer - or delete the question. Up to you :)

Comment: Have a heart guys, the OP only wants a little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bboybeatle, your "negative margin of half the divs width" idea is spot on, and not at all difficult to implement. Just include the required `marginTop` and `marginLeft` settings in the two animations.

```
$(function() {
    var cssMap1a = {
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    };
    var cssMap1b = {
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        marginTop: -10,
        marginLeft: -10
    };
    var cssMap2a = {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    };
    var cssMap2b = {
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        marginTop: 0,
        marginLeft: 0
    };

    $(".button1").click(function () {
        $('.london').css(cssMap1a).animate(cssMap1b, 300);
    });
    $(".button2").click(function () {
        $('.london').css(cssMap2a).animate(cssMap2b, 300);
    });
});
```

And here's a *[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lemaz445/)*. Fiddles are not difficult to set up. Hopefully this will help you next time you need to ask a question here.

As you will see :

- "London" and the buttons are moved to a better position for demo purposes
- The colour changes are separated out as separate css maps. They didn't work in the fiddle when included in the animation maps. jQuery needs a plugin to animate colours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for that @Roamer-1888, I actually used some variables to make it slightly easier to apply the margin. I will remember that technique of putting multiple css properties in a variable..

Heres a snippet of my code I ended up using...

```
londonMargin = london/2 - london;
$('.london').animate({ width:london,  height:london, marginLeft:londonMargin, marginBottom:londonMargin }, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I put together a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4kng8wjg/) that has a function to which you pass an element name, the x and y coordinates of the center, and it will position the element in the larger element.

JS

```
var myelement = $('.boxdiv');
var myelement2 = $('.boxdiv2');

putmycenter( myelement, 90, 90 );
putmycenter( myelement2, 160, 280 );


function putmycenter (element, x, y)
{
  var boxdivxcentre = element.width()/2;
  var boxdivycentre = element.height()/2;
  var boxdivposx = (x - boxdivxcentre);
  var boxdivposy = (y - boxdivycentre);
  element.css({
                  "top" : boxdivposy + 'px',
                  "left" : boxdivposx + 'px'
                  });

}
```